# Is L2TP preshared key anywhere stored in plaintext on w2k8?

Tags: windows-server-2008, rras, l2tp

Some time ago I have configured l2tp vpn server on w2k8 rras that uses preshared key. Now I am trying to setup another client but the key that I have documented does not seem to be correct. I have full access to server and one client that both have correct key remembered but asterisks are all I can see. Any ideas where to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password is stored in an encrypted form that's next to impossible to manually decrypt. PSK VPN connections really weren't meant for your use case, Certificate based authentication was, which is why you're finding it hard to do what you want.

Comment: Yup, it was typical case of "temporary solutions becoming permanent". I'll wait another day or two and then accept.

Comment: Please elaborate by providing a proof link.